# null responseXML.xml value in Chrome

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, xmlhttprequest

A have the following problem. My code sends the the HTTP Request to ASP Handler:

```
var xmlRequest = !window.XMLHttpRequest ? new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :      new XMLHttpRequest; 
xmlRequest.open("GET", "Handler.ashx?value25="+$('#joKod').val()+"&operType=3");
xmlRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
xmlRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if (xmlRequest.readyState == 4)
    {
       if (xmlRequest.status == 200)
       {   
          alert(xmlRequest.responseXML.xml);       
       }
    }
}   
xmlRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml"); 
xmlRequest.send('xml');
```

My handler creates XML answer

```
XmlDocument xd=Scoring.CheckLinkFirma(okpo);
resp.Clear();
resp.ContentType = "text/xml";
xd.Save(resp.Output);
```

And sends it back:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
   <jo status="client">abc</jo>
   <jo status="client">dfh</jo>
</Root>
```

In Exlorer responseXML.xml has value, but Chrome and FF it is undefined???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in jQuery. Hope it will help someone

```
$.ajax
({    
    type: "GET",
    url: "Handler.ashx?value25="+$('#joKod').val()+"&operType=3", 
    dataType: "text",
    cache: true,              
    success: function(xml)
    {             
         if (xml) 
         {
            var myXml = $($.parseXML(xml)).find('Root');    
         }
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Because that is IE only property . If you want to get an XML you can do something like this:

```
function XMLToString(oXML)
{   
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {}//Standards First
 else if (window.ActiveXObject) {return oXML.xml;}//Proprietary Second
 else {return (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(oXML);}//other browsers
}
alert(XMLToString(xmlRequest.responseXML))
```

Or you can try to get xml text from `xmlRequest.responseText`

Comment: Thanks, XMLToString makes the xmlRequest.responseXML property which is already XML and there is no need to make it xml again. Chrome debug shows that the xmlRequest.responseXML is object and it has tags. But they are all undefined. And the nodeName field of any node is #text

Comment: `responseXML.xml` in IE returns **text** of XML document, not an object. But .xml is IE only property of XMLDocument object, so if you want to take a text of xml document crossbrowser - you can use XMLToString function from my answer. It also accepts XML Nodes.

Comment: +1 This is what I needed. Probably should have been accepted as the answer.